# SQL Query to get min and max date per year date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I have a query which is loading a per year sales of a given Tenant. Using this code below, I am able to produce this result (see image table)

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,date) [month]
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR (DATE) = @Year1 THEN gsc END), 0) AS 'Year1'
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR (DATE) = @Year2 THEN gsc END), 0) AS 'Year2'
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR (DATE) = @Year3 THEN gsc END), 0) AS 'Year3'
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR (DATE) = @Year4 THEN gsc END), 0) AS 'Year4'
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR (DATE) = @Year5 THEN gsc END), 0) AS 'Year5'
INTO #LRSalesAnalysis
FROM dailymod 
WHERE tenantcode = @RP 
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(MM,DATENAME(month,date)+' 01 2011')
```

*Part of the code, take note that parameters @Year1-5 have value like (2011,2012 etc)*

result

[image]

What I want now is to get the minimum date and maximum date per year. RESULTING TO SOMETHING LIKE THIS

[image]

*The source database is actually a collection of sales per date. So I want to get the max and min date found in the given date range  (year)*

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the done with the same technique you are already using. Only it's two queries, one for `min`, one for `max`, that you'd glue together with `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 
  'Min Date' AS what
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year1 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year1'
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year2 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year2'
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year3 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year3'
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year4 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year4'
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year5 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year5'
FROM dailymod 
WHERE tenantcode = @RP 
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Max Date' AS what
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year1 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year1'
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year2 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year2'
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year3 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year3'
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year4 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year4'
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year5 THEN DATE END) AS 'Year5'
FROM dailymod 
WHERE tenantcode = @RP;
```